# Why doesn't the load any data when I enter the following code when the page exists:

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my codes, please tell me what went wrong:

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.allendowney.com', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://www.allendowney.com/wp/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(1000)
    if (len(data) < 1): break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? I am able to run the code & am not seeing any problems

Comment: @NatKSS although it displays an output, it is not able to extract the content of the page and you can see the description of the page says 'Error 404: No Page Found' in the beginning of the output.